# Change unverified email id in laravel before verification

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I want to change signup email which user enter incorrect during signup.I add a textbox to correct email id in verification page but when the update code is hit its show "email is not verified"

Here is the code to update unverified email id

```
public function updateemail($email)
{
   date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
$email_verified_at = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
 return DB::table('students')->where('email', $email)->update(array('email' => $email));   
}
```

Ajax code is here

```
$("#resendnew").click(function(){
        
        var email =  $('#emailnew').val();
        
         $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                 
                url: "/register/updateemail/"+email, 
                success: function (response) {
                    
                    console.log('response',response);
                   alert("Data Updated");
                     
                },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log('err',error);
                    alert("Data Error");
                }
            });


    });
});
```

[image: Here is View]